# Type family evaluation in dependent kind signature

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-families

Consider the following:

```hs
type Nat :: Type
data Nat = Z | S Nat

type Fin :: Nat -> Type
data Fin n
  where
  FZ :: Fin ('S n)
  FS :: Fin n -> Fin ('S n)

type Length :: [k] -> Nat
type family Length xs
  where
  Length '[] = 'Z
  Length (_ ': xs) = Length xs
```

Given all this, it seems like it should be possible to define a type level function that maps a type level list and an index smaller than its length to the type stored at the corresponding position.

```hs
type Get :: forall k. forall (l :: [k]) -> Fin (Length l) -> k
type family Get l i
  where
  Get (x ': xs) 'FZ = x
  Get (_ ': xs) ('FS i) = Get xs i
```

But this blows up with the following error:

```hs
• Illegal type synonym family application ‘Length @k xs’ in instance:
    Get @k ((':) @k x xs) ('FZ @(Length @k xs))
• In the equations for closed type family ‘Get’
  In the type family declaration for ‘Get’
```

So it seems GHC is not happy with the evaluation of the `Length` type family in the dependent kind signature. Is there some way to convince GHC that it's OK to define such a function? Alternatively, is there some workaround I can use to describe the dependently-kinded operation of indexing into a type level list?

Comment: @chi No, I don't believe so. The basic idea of `Fin` is that `Fin n` should have `n` inhabitants. So `Fin 'Z` should be uninhabitable, which would not be the case if we had `FZ :: Fin 'Z`.

Comment: @chi It is "exactly n", but you nevertheless need `FZ :: Fin ('S n)` to represent the "first" of the inhabitants of `Fin n` for any strictly positive `n`. If it were `FZ :: Fin ('S 'Z)` you would be unable to finitely construct any inhabitant of `Fin ('S ('S 'Z))`.

Comment: @chi, I think of `Fin n` as representing any natural strictly less than `n`. For any `k`, `0 < 1+ k`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm personally not aware of a way to make this work (hoping someone else is). That said, we can work around the need to evaluate a type family in the kind signature if we absorb `Length` into the definition of `Fin`. In other words, we can create a special purpose indexing type for lists that mirrors `Fin (Length l)`:

```hs
type Index :: [k] -> Type
data Index xs
  where
  Head :: Index (x ': xs)
  Next :: Index xs -> Index (x ': xs)
```

Now we can use that to write a variation of `Get`:

```hs
type Get :: forall k. forall (l :: [k]) -> Index l -> k
type family Get l i
  where
  Get (x ': xs) 'Head = x
  Get (_ ': xs) ('Next i) = Get xs i
```

Which seems to work:

```hs
type Test = Get '[Int, String, Bool] (Next (Next Head))
```

```
> :k! Test
Test :: *
= Bool
```

This approach is kind of gross and anti-compositional, but I suppose it works.